# Difference between npm audit fix --force and - npm audit fix?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, methods

Difference between - 'npm audit fix --force' and - 'npm audit fix'?

Comment: Please do a Google search first before posting a question. See here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Comment: On the other hand, if you've already looked at the documentation, but didn't fully understand it, please elaborate what was not clear. Also useful: https://dev.to/bbenefield89/fixing-npm-dependencies-vulnerabilities-6p8

Comment: @ba_ul thanks for the the link it help me a lot about the high & moderate I have clear understanding before I didn't mind about what the console is telling me now I get it.  https://dev.to/bbenefield89/fixing-npm-dependencies-vulnerabilities-6p8

Comment: alot has been change on the newest updates but yours is like core fundamentals and has given me wide range for useful developer insights.

Comment: been reading it today and still making it a reference for my angular firebase web app

Comment: Of course there's the obligatory How to Ask a Question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

updates to top-level dependencies, not just compatible ones:

Comment: what do you mean?